# Build electron windows app with accessible resources

Tags: cordova, electron, electron-builder

After "cordova build electron --production" I get an compiled exe-file and an "win-unpacked" folder, but I can neither edit/change my source files (mp4, json) in there.

Is there any way to leave the resources (original www-folder) untuched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Just put this in your package.json:

```
"build": {
    "asar": false
  },
```